# What are the earliest written accounts of Sub-Saharan Africa from the outside?

Tags: africa, resource

I've been researching African ethnography recently, and this path has led me to looking for early accounts of Sub-Saharan Africa. That they come from non-residents likely goes without saying, but I specify this as to not be Eurocentric.

I've done a bit of research to try to find out what and where these accounts may be, but I'm coming up empty-handed. So if I were to visit an academic library for the earliest, surviving written accounts of Sub-Saharan Africa, what would the title/author of these books be?

Comment: Note: if we're ever able to decipher [Meroitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meroitic_language), it would push back the earliest available (non-Egyptian) accounts significantly, though these would of course be African not non-African accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the UNESCO *General History of Africa* (vol 1),

> The ancient authors' information was scanty and fitful, especially in
>   relation to West Africa. Herodotus, Manethon, the Elder Pliny, Strabo
>   and some others tell us little more than of occasional journeys or
>   raids across the Sahara, or of maritime tentatives down the Atlantic
>   coast, and the authenticity of some of these accounts is often the
>   subject of lively dispute among modern scholars.

However, we're on firmer ground with ***[Periplus of the Erythraean Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periplus_of_the_Erythraean_Sea)*** which dates from around the **middle of the 1st century AD** and mentions [Rhapta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhapta), believed to be on the coast of modern-day Tanzania. The author is unknown but the was *probably* from north Africa. On Rhapta, [this source says](https://archive.org/details/periplusoferythr00schouoft/page/28):

> there is ivory in great quantity, and tortoise-shell. Along this coast
>   live men of piratical habits, very great in stature, and under
>   separate chiefs for each place.

The UNESCO *General History of Africa* also mentions

> **Claudius Ptolemy** (c. **150 of our era**, though the version that has come
>   down to us seems to relate more to c. 400) and of **Cosmas Indicopleustes** (**647**) are still major sources for the early history of East Africa.

Among Ptolemy's maps was this one below:

[image]

*Attrib: [http://maps.bpl.org [CC BY 2.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quarta_Africae_tabula_(7537883120).jpg)*

[Ptolemy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/716072?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), who was Greco-Roman but lived in Alexandria,

> gave to the western coast of Africa, as far as what is now called
>   Sierra Leone, considerable detail in regard to names and natural
>   features

[Cosmas Indicopleustes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmas_Indicopleustes) was a *Greek* merchant from *Alexandria*. He is best known for travelling to India, but [he also went to Eritrea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmas_Indicopleustes) (which is [sub-Saharan Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Saharan_Africa)):

> He happened to be in Adulis on the Red Sea Coast of modern Eritrea at
>   the time (**c. 525 AD**) when the King of Axum was preparing a military
>   expedition to attack the Jewish king Dhu Nuwas in Yemen, who had
>   recently been persecuting Christians.

For most of sub-Saharan Africa, though:

> There is a huge area where until the fifteenth century the written
>   source is non-existent; and what is a second-rate Arabic source for,
>   say, the Maghrib, takes on prime importance for the Niger Basin.

*Source: UNESCO General History of Africa (vol 1)*

Answer (score 4):

Originally, the question asked for a non-African source, which I interpreted as an account from someone who originally lived outside Africa. The question has now been refined to include any accounts outside of sub-Saharan Africa, which would include early Egyptian accounts and others such as the Egypt-dwelling Greek/Roman sources in Lars's answer. I won't attempt to capture those, so what follows focuses on the earliest accounts from sources located entirely outside Africa.

The earliest account of Sub-Saharan Africa by a non-African that I can find is *Kitab al-Budan* by [Ya'qubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya%27qubi) in 872 CE.

One of the English translations you might look for is [*The Works of Ibn Wāḍiḥ al-Yaʿqūbī*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LnxTDwAAQBAJ&q=africa#v=snippet&q=766&f=false). Here is an excerpt:

> Whoever travels south by road from Sijilmasa toward the land of the Blacks,<sup>766</sup> (inhabited by) various black tribes, travels through wasteland and desert for a distance of fifty days' journey. One then encounters a group of Sanhaja called the Anbiya in the desert; they have no fixed dwelling.
>
> 766 Arabic *ard al-sudan*: for Arabic geographers the term covers all of sub-Saharan Africa, not merely the modern Sudan.

[*Trade in the Ancient Sahara and Beyond*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6ug7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=Ya%27qubi+sub-saharan+africa&source=bl&ots=hzvg5k-tOD&sig=ACfU3U28pf5yelb7pf08uvHUm3HahJmJBg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxy92W1pjgAhURY6wKHTCyDdwQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Ya%27qubi%20sub-saharan%20africa&f=false) claims that the first accounts to the outside world of sub-Saharan West Africa came from Muslim traders. It mentions Ya'qubi as a source, so he may be as early as it gets.